# Create unique id for uploaded image

Tags: php, file, file-upload, ftp, file-rename

How to create unique id for uploaded file using this code.

Code uploads the image, but when you upload it using iPhone all images are come as image.jpg. So I need a function to rename existing file or just to create unique id for each.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST"> Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" /> </form>
<?php 
function findexts ($filename)  {  $filename = strtolower($filename) ;  $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;  $n = count($exts)-1;  $exts = $exts[$n];  return $exts;  }   

$ext = findexts ($_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 


$ran = rand () ; 
$ran2 = $ran.".";  
$target = "uploads/";

if(file_exists("uploads/$filename")) unlink("uploads/$filename");move_uploaded_file($target, "uploads/$filename");

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))  { echo "The file has been uploaded as ".$ran2.$ext; }  else { echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; } 
$target = $target . $ran2.$ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uniqid()` function for unique image names. It gets two parameters. First: prefix, Second: more entropy.

See details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST"> Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" /> </form>
    <?php 
    function findexts ($filename)  {  
       $filename = strtolower($filename) ;  
       $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ;  
       $n = count($exts)-1;  
       $exts = $exts[$n];  return $exts;  
    }   

    $ext = findexts ($_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 

    //unique image
    $new_image_name = uniqid("IMG_",false);
    $final_name = $new_image_name.".".$ext;

    //Target directory
    $target = "uploads/";

    if(file_exists("uploads/$final_name")) unlink("uploads/$final_name");move_uploaded_file($target,"uploads/$final_name");

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))  { echo "The file has been uploaded as ".$final_name; }  else { echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; } 
    $target = $target . $final_name;
```

Comment: WARNING: The `uniqid()` function does guarantee a unique ID. Please read documentation and its comments for full explanation http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php